# Facebook Real-time Update: Validating X-Hub-Signature SHA1 signature in Java

Tags: java, facebook, sha, real-time-updates

When Facebook sends real-time updates, they include a X-Hub-Signature in the HTTP header. According to [their documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime), they're using SHA1 and the application secret as the key.

Based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390543/facebook-real-time-update-validating-x-hub-signature-sha1-signature-in-c-sharp) for C# I tried to verify the signature like this ('body' is the message sent by facebook in the body of the request):

```
String passedSignature = req.getHeader("X-Hub-Signature").substring(5);
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(FACEBOOK_SECRET.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), "HmacSHA1"));
String calculatedSignature = Hex.encodeHexString(hmac.doFinal(body.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
logger.debug("Calculated sigSHA1: " + calculatedSignature + " passedSignature: " + passedSignature);
```

But the passedSignature is always different from the calculatedSignature.

Anybody can help solving the problem?

Comment: You don't need to define `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` as the FB secret only uses Latin1 characters (ISO8859-1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out the code is correct, I was using the wrong key :-/

Anyway I hope this could help somebody else.

Comment: Yeah me too! :-( One should use the App Secret Token, not the Verify Token ('hub.verify_token') used in verification request.

Comment: @Uhlen, Thanks a lot. I was trying the same thing. :)